# Ruby on Rails: blog post doesnt render in HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I have a posts model that I use to make blog posts on a page of my site. I'd like for the content of the post to be HTML formatted, but am having trouble getting it to actually render in HTML. It only shows up as plain text on the blog page. I am using Rails_Admin if that makes a difference.

---

`posts` view:

```
#blog_page
- @posts_list.each do |post|
    %ul.post
        %li= post.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
        %li.title= post.title
        %li.author
            = 'By: '
            = post.author
        %li.content= RedCloth.new(post.content).to_html

= paginate @posts_list
```

---

`post` model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :content, :title, :author
has_many :comments

validates :title, :presence => true
validates :content, :presence => true

end
```

---

`posts` controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:new, :create]

# GET /posts
def index
    @posts_list = Post.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(5)
    render 'blog'
end

# GET /posts/
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    render 'show'
end

def new
    if !current_user.admin?
        redirect_to '/blog'
    end
    @post = Post.new
end

# POST /posts
def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
        if current_user.admin?
          respond_to do |format|
            if @post.save
              format.html  { redirect_to('/posts', :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
              format.json  { render :json => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
        else
          flash[:notice] = 'Error creating post!<br/>'.html_safe
            @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
              flash[:notice] << "<br/>".html_safe
              flash[:notice] << msg
            end
          format.html  { render :action => "new" }
          format.json  { render :json => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    else
      redirect_to '/blog'
    end
end

end
```

Comment: You have shown no CSS. Without CSS, it's bound to look boring and plain. Are you sure that's not the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "plain text"? Do you just need to make it html_safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view has to be like this:

```
#blog_page
- @posts_list.each do |post|
    %ul.post
        %li= post.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
        %li.title= post.title
        %li.author
            = 'By: '
            = post.author
        %li.content= RedCloth.new(post.content).to_html.html_safe

= paginate @posts_list
```

You could also create a helper for that:

```
def post_content( post ) 
  RedCloth.new(post.content).to_html.html_safe
end
```

And just use it in your view.

Comment: Still not getting any html to display in the view. Looking at the page source, I see the html markup but its not rendering. I added the helper, and used it in the view.

Comment: It was getting overwritten by inherited css. figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

create a partial called '_post.html.haml' under views/posts

Now in your posts view, just use:

```
=render @posts_list
```

In your '_post.html.haml' partial:

```
%ul.post
    %li= post.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
    %li.title= post.title
    %li.author By: #{post.author}
    %li.content
      != RedCloth.new(post.content).to_html
```